# JS: Lodash partition by a array of predicates

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I got the following to work for me. Just curious if there is a "better" way to do it.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': false }
];
 
_.partition(users, ({user}) => {
   if (_.includes(['fred', 'pebbles'], user)) {
      return true
   } else {
     return false
   }
})
```

Don't know how scalable this solution is for a massive list of users?

Comment: Why not `_.includes(['fred', 'pebbles'], user)` ?

Comment: nice, thank you for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting question for me. I have prepared a code with some measurements. Maybe this will help you make the right decision.

Regarding your question, I believe if you need max performance, than you have to use minimal complicated code. Lodash is a great tool and it makes code more readable, but it's not a choise when you need performance.

```js
(function() {
    const users = [
      { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': true },
      { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': false }
    ];

    function function1 (queryArray) {
      return _.partition(users, ({user}) => _.includes(queryArray, user));
    }
    function function2 (queryArray) {
        const _output = [[], []];
        users.reduce((output, user) => {
            if(queryArray.indexOf(user.user) > -1) output[0].push(user);
            else output[1].push(user);
            return output;
        }, _output);
        return _output;
    }
    function function3 (queryArray) {
        const output = [[], []];
        for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            const user = users[i];
            if(queryArray.indexOf(user.user) > -1) output[0].push(user);
            else output[1].push(user);
        }
        return output;
    }


    const iterations = 1000000;
    const queryArray = ['fred', 'pebbles'];

    console.time('Function #1');
    for(let i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
        function1(queryArray);
    }
    console.timeEnd('Function #1');

    console.time('Function #2');
    for(let i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
        function2(queryArray);
    }
    console.timeEnd('Function #2');

    console.time('Function #3');
    for(let i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
        function3(queryArray);
    }
    console.timeEnd('Function #3');
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the results on my machine. You may have other results in your browser, but the ratio will be about the same. On average, the lodash solution takes about twice as long time.

```
Function #1: 787.700ms
Function #2: 466.300ms
Function #3: 275.900ms
```

Comment: You should make `['fred', 'pebbles']` an argument to get rid of the cost of an array build in the benchmark.

Comment: @AKX You are absolutely right, but my goal wasn't to create a best solution. All the functions should work with similar conditions. Anyway, I've updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `if (someBoolean) { return true; } else { return false; }` is completely equivalent to `return someBoolean`. So your code may be simplified:

```
const [fredOrPebblesUsers, otherUsers] = 
  _.partition(users, ({user}) => _.includes(['fred', 'pebbles'], user));
```

Now, how scalable is this? well, you already have the complete array of `users` in memory, you'll just create two more arrays with references (not the values themselves) to those objects. It would be relevant to know how are you going to use those partitioned values, if you need all at once or lazy libraries like [lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) would be helpful.

Speed-wise, the gains of a for-loop over an arrow function have already been discussed by @Max Martynov. IMO, only if you saw that is the bottleneck in your app should you change a nice abstraction with arrow functions for a clunky for-loop.

> _.includes(['fred', 'pebbles'], user)

Just two values to compare? If your real code has more values, you should use a `Set` to have O(1) comparisons instead of O(n).